# 2nd Legend canvas not showing in wpf chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been struggling with this for some time now. The problem relates to adding a second legend canvas in a wpf chart. I'm referencing Jack Yu's book Practical WPF Charts and Graphics LineChartWithLegend.xaml file. In the xaml file, I added the new legend canvas named "legendCanvas2". I've changed the code behind to add a second instance of the legend in the AddChart() method. The problem is the second legend does not show inside chartCanvas. I suspect this issue has to do with multiple canvas containers inside chartCanvas but not sure. Any help with alternative ways I can display two legends inside chartCanvas would be appreciated.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="LineCharts.LineChartWithLegend"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Line Chart with Legend" Height="400" Width="500">

    <Grid Name="grid1" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="column1" Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" 
                Text="Title"/>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbXLabel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" 
               Text="X Axis"/>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" Name="tbYLabel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" 
                Text="Y Axis">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid  Margin="0" x:Name ="chartGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
               ClipToBounds="True" Background="Transparent" SizeChanged="chartGrid_SizeChanged" />
        <Canvas Margin="2" Name="textCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Canvas Name="chartCanvas" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Canvas Name="legendCanvas" Background="Transparent" />
                <Canvas Name="legendCanvas2" Background="Transparent" />
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind

```
    private void AddChart()
    {
        cs = new ChartStyleGridlines();
        lg = new Legend();
        lg2 = new Legend();
        dc = new DataCollection();
        ds = new DataSeries();

        cs.ChartCanvas = chartCanvas;
        cs.TextCanvas = textCanvas;
        cs.Title = "Sine and Cosine Chart";
        cs.Xmin = 0;
        cs.Xmax = 7;
        cs.Ymin = -1.5;
        cs.Ymax = 1.5;
        cs.YTick = 0.5;
        cs.GridlinePattern = ChartStyleGridlines.GridlinePatternEnum.Dot;
        cs.GridlineColor = Brushes.Black;
        cs.AddChartStyle(tbTitle, tbXLabel, tbYLabel);

        // Draw Sine curve:
        ds.LineColor = Brushes.Blue;
        ds.LineThickness = 1;
        ds.SeriesName = "Sine";
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        {
            double x = i / 5.0;
            double y = Math.Sin(x);
            ds.LineSeries.Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        dc.DataList.Add(ds);

        // Draw cosine curve:
        ds = new DataSeries();
        ds.LineColor = Brushes.Red;
        ds.SeriesName = "Cosine";
        ds.LinePattern = DataSeries.LinePatternEnum.DashDot;
        ds.LineThickness = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        {
            double x = i / 5.0;
            double y = Math.Cos(x);
            ds.LineSeries.Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        dc.DataList.Add(ds);

        // Draw sine^2 curve:
        ds = new DataSeries();
        ds.LineColor = Brushes.DarkGreen;
        ds.SeriesName = "Sine^2";
        ds.LinePattern = DataSeries.LinePatternEnum.Dot;
        ds.LineThickness = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        {
            double x = i / 5.0;
            double y = Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x);
            ds.LineSeries.Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        dc.DataList.Add(ds);

        dc.AddLines(cs);

        lg.LegendCanvas = legendCanvas;
        lg.IsLegend = true;
        lg.IsBorder = true;
        lg.LegendPosition = Legend.LegendPositionEnum.NorthWest;
        lg.AddLegend(cs.ChartCanvas, dc);

        lg2 = new Legend();
        lg2.LegendCanvas = legendCanvas2;
        lg2.IsLegend = true;
        lg2.IsBorder = true;
        lg2.LegendPosition = Legend.LegendPositionEnum.NorthEast;
        lg2.AddLegend(cs.ChartCanvas, dc);
    }

    private void chartGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textCanvas.Width = chartGrid.ActualWidth;
        textCanvas.Height = chartGrid.ActualHeight;
        legendCanvas.Children.Clear();
        legendCanvas2.Children.Clear();
        chartCanvas.Children.RemoveRange(2, chartCanvas.Children.Count - 1); // changed index from 1 to 2
        textCanvas.Children.RemoveRange(1, textCanvas.Children.Count - 1);
        AddChart(); 
    }
```

Comment: There is a statement in chartGrid_SizeChanged() which removes the children in chartCanvas. It's index was set at one but there are three children set in chartCanvas. For this case, the second legend is shown but hidden since chartGrid_SizeChanged() clears and updates chartCanvas. Changing the index to two fixes the problem. It would make sense to keep track of incrementing this index somehow to avoid hard coding an integer constant.

Comment: added corrected method chartGrid_SizeChanged() in Code-Behind